# Mathematical Induction vs Strong Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In Rosen's book [Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 8th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/125967651X) it is mentioned that:

> You may be surprised that mathematical induction and strong induction are equivalent.  That is, each can be shown to be a valid proof technique assuming that the other is valid.

One of the examples given for strong induction in the book is the following:

> Suppose we can reach the first and second rungs of an infinite ladder,
> and we know that if we can reach a rung, then we can reach two rungs
> higher … prove that we can reach every rung using strong induction

If the two proof techniques are "equivalent", how can I prove the above example using mathematical induction (as opposed to strong induction)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate for [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is simple: Instead of proving "For every n ≥ 0, I can reach rung n on the ladder", you prove "For every n ≥ 0, I can reach rung n on the ladder, plus I can reach rung n-1 if n ≥ 1".

The statement is true for n = 0. The induction step n->n+1 works for n = 0 (because I can reach rungs 0 and 1); for n ≥ 1 I could reach rung n and n-1. Since I can reach rung n-1, I can also reach rung (n-1) + 2 = n+1, therefore I can reach rung n and n+1, so the statement is true for n+1.

Comment: There is a general reduction from complete induction to standard induction, which is how you show that the two are equivalent.